# 'Check for Letter' Validation Not Working

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I'm running some functions to verify that the user-entered text in a form contains at least one number and letter.  It doesn't seem to be working.  Since the two functions are nearly identical, I'll just post one of them:

```
function hasALetter(textField){
    //returns true or false based on whether or not the text field has at least one letter inside it    
    console.log("Checking for letters...");

    var hasLetter = false;

    for(var i=0, checkLength=textField.length; i<checkLength; i++){
        var letter = textField.substr(i,1);
        console.log("letter = " + letter);
        if(isNan(letter) == false){
            hasLetter = false;
        }
    }
    if(hasLetter == true){
        return true;
    }
}
```

The log ("letter = " + letter) never shows up in my console.  I'm probably missing something silly, but it doesn't seem to be completing the function.

For reference, here is how I'm calling the functions:

```
if(pwd.value.length > 9){

            var pwdLetter = hasALetter(pwd);
            var pwdNumber = hasADigit(pwd);

            if(pwdLetter==true){
                if(pwdNumber==true){
```

*Yes, I'm aware that it's very messy, but I'm still learning.  I'm sure there's more advanced/cleaner ways of doing this validation, but for the purposes of my schooling, I'm doing it like this for now.*

Comment: OMG, what's going on here? 1) Getting a single character with `substr` 2) isNa*N* 3) if(true) return true else return false is unnecessary 4) log after return statement. This can be done a *lot* better...

Comment: @Harmen > I'm sure it can, but since I'm still in my first Javascript class of my college program, 'substr' is what the prof gave us to work with.  Also, I thought I'd taken out the 'return false' statements.  :P

Comment: @GnomeSlice: textField.charAt(i) returns a letter at that position; 'return hasLetter' should be better, no condition statements ;) ...

Comment: @GnomeSlice: do you check only if textField has at least one letter?

Comment: What browser are you using for debugging this?

Comment: @Maxym > Yes, it has to have at least one.  Currently, no matter what I enter into the field, it says I need to add a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to check if a string has a letter is the Regular Expression:

```
function hasLetter(str){
  // check for characters between a and z
  // i flag makes it case insensitive
  return /[a-z]/i.test(str);
}
```

If you want to loop through the string and also want to use the `isNaN` function, this would do:

```
function hasLetter(str){

  // loop through every character
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){

    // check if the i-th character is not a number
    if(isNaN(str[i])){

      // if so, return true
      return true;
    }
  }

  // if the loop has finished and no letters have been found, return false
  return false;
}
```

But I would not recommend this method, because `isNaN` checks whether the first argument is a number or not. First of all, not all characters that aren't numbers are letters. Secondly, the argument you pass in is a string (`str[i]` returns a character of type string, even if it is a digit)

Comment: Won't this always end up returning false once the loop has completed?

Comment: @Harmen: str[i] won't work in IE, `str.charAt(i)` is standard and crossbrowser way to do it. E.g. 'asd'[1] in FF and Chrome will return 's', but IE will return 'undefined'. Be careful...

Comment: @GnomeSlice: if loop is completed, then there is no letter; so yes it will return false. Otherwise it will return true and leave that function from inside loop

Comment: @Maxym I'm very sure accessing a character of a string by index with square brackets will work in IE. Literal string notation + index accessing might not work, as you say.

Comment: @Harmen: I'm using IE9, `var str = 'asd'; alert( str[1] );` shows me 'undefined'. I'm pretty sure the same result I will get using IE8 and others. Then what's wrong with this example?

Comment: It's *still* not working.  Looks like it's always returning false.  :/

Comment: @GnomeSlice: function posted by Harmen takes string, looking at your code you send input element as parameter. Change to hasALetter(pwd.value) and it should work; the same with hasADigit

Comment: @Maxym > Yes, that got it working.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 4):

It's "isNaN", not "isNan" ... ... also, if it's **not** a number, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's not a letter; in fact the logic seems backwards, or upside-down.

If "isNaN" returns `true`, then it's not a number. Is it a letter?  Well, you have to check. If "isNaN" returns `false`, then all you know is that it's one of the characters '0' through '9'.

The whole thing is much better done with a regex, but if this is homework it may be that that approach can't be used. You can check to see if a character is a letter with something like:

```
function isLetter(c) {
  c = c.toUpperCase();
  return c >= "A" && c <= "Z";
}
```

Comment: My group hasn't learned anything beyond this right now. I thought the logic seemed a little wonky, but this is what I've got to work with for now. You're right about the typo, but fixing it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of regular expressions, here are a couple of quick functions.

```
    function hasALetter(text)
    {
        var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]");
        if(text.match(regex))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    function hasANumber(text)
    {
        var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]");
        if(text.match(regex))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use conditions? why not to write simple 'return text.match(regex);' instead??

Comment: I tried that first and for whatever reason it returned the first matching character.

Comment: I don't know if it browser specific, but when string does not match regexp, then FF returns 'null', so yeah, to return boolean value better to write 'return ( text.match(regex) != null );'

Comment: And for the best solution look at Harmen's answer ;) (just use test function of regexp variable)